# extend class with IB_DESIGNABLE obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I found `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable` very usefull to bring setter possibility directly to the storyboard.

I use it in a swift projet that way

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
@IBDesignable extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable var addBorderTop: CGFloat {
        set {
            addBorderUtility(0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: newValue, color: layer.borderColor)
        }
        get {
            return 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var addBorderBottom: CGFloat {
        set {
            addBorderUtility(0, y: frame.height - newValue, width: frame.width, height: newValue, color: layer.borderColor)

        }
        get {
            return 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var addBorderLeft: CGFloat {
        set {
            addBorderUtility(0, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.height, color: layer.borderColor)
        }
        get {
            return 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var addBorderRight: CGFloat {
        set {
            addBorderUtility(frame.width - newValue, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.height, color:  layer.borderColor)
        }
        get {
            return 0
        }
    }

    private func addBorderUtility(_ x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, color: CGColor?) {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color
        border.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

this is working like a charms. So I decided to do the same thing on an objective-c project, trying to extend UIView here is hhow it looks like

UIView+Border.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView ()
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectale CGFloat addBorderTop;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectale CGFloat addBorderBottom;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectale CGFloat addBorderLeft;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectale CGFloat addBorderRight;
@end
```

UIView+Border.m

```
#import "UIView+Border.h"

@interface UIView ()

IB_DESIGNABLE
@implementation UIView ()

- (void) setAddBorderTop: (CGFloat) newValue
{
    addBorderUtility(0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: newValue, color: layer.borderColor)
}

- (void) setAddBorderBottom: (CGFloat) newValue
{
    addBorderUtility(0, y: frame.height - newValue, width: frame.width, height: newValue, color: layer.borderColor)
}

- (void) setAddBorderLeft: (CGFloat) newValue
{
    addBorderUtility(0, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.height, color: layer.borderColor)
}

- (void) setAddBorderRight: (CGFloat) newValue
{
    addBorderUtility(frame.width - newValue, y: 0, width: newValue, height: frame.height, color: layer.borderColor)
}

- (void) addBorderUtility: (CGFloat):x y:(CGFloat)y width:(CGFloat)width  height:(CGFloat)height color:(CGColor)color
{
    CALayer *border = [CALayer init]
    border.backgroundColor = color
    border.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    layer.addSublayer(border)
}
@end
```

but none of my custom variabble are settable from the right menu on the storyboard. I also tried to add an `User Defined Runtime Attributes` having the same name as one of my custome variable,nothing happened once you run the app.

any idea how to do that ? thanks

Comment: you have a typo here `IBInspectale` is `IBInspectable` instead

Comment: also should be `@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat addBorderTop;` without the `*`

Comment: thanks I update the question.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is many mistake in you Objective-C code, I have update it.
You have to use `CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];` instead of `CALayer *border = [CALayer init];`.

Please check this code :

UIView+Border.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Border)
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat addBorderTop;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat addBorderBottom;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat addBorderLeft;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat addBorderRight;

@end
```

UIView+Border.m

```
#import "UIView+Border.h"

IB_DESIGNABLE
@implementation UIView (Border)

@dynamic addBorderTop;
@dynamic addBorderBottom;
@dynamic addBorderLeft;
@dynamic addBorderRight;

- (void) setAddBorderTop: (CGFloat)newValue
{
    [self addBorderUtility:0 y:0 width:self.frame.size.width height:newValue color:self.layer.borderColor];
}

- (void) setAddBorderBottom: (CGFloat) newValue
{
    [self addBorderUtility:0 y:self.frame.size.height - newValue width:self.frame.size.width height:newValue color:self.layer.borderColor];
}

- (void) setAddBorderLeft: (CGFloat) newValue
{
    [self addBorderUtility:0 y:0 width:newValue height:self.frame.size.height color:self.layer.borderColor];
}

- (void) setAddBorderRight: (CGFloat) newValue
{
    [self addBorderUtility:self.frame.size.width - newValue y:0 width:newValue height:self.frame.size.height color:self.layer.borderColor];
}

- (void) addBorderUtility:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y width:(CGFloat)width  height:(CGFloat)height color:(CGColorRef)color
{
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    border.backgroundColor = color;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [self.layer addSublayer:border];
}
@end
```

Comment: I did follow your instruction but no change are visible from the attribute inspector. suprinsigly Xcode never show up my old mistakes

Comment: oops, made another typo again. everything is woking now thanks. but do you have any idea why xcode not showing up typo error from those file ? anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining the categories correctly. You need to specify a category name otherwise the compiler will interpret this as a redeclaration of `UIView`. Try `@interface UIView (Design)` and `@implementation UIView (Design)`.